# What is a scalable lock?

Tags: c++, locking

What is a scalable lock? And how is it different from a non-scalable lock? I first saw this term in the context of the TBB rw-lock, and couldn't decide which to use.

In addition, is there any rw-lock that prioritizes readers over writers?

Comment: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/lec/l-mcs.html

Comment: [Summary + different variants in Pascal(?)](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/synchronization/pseudocode/rw.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no formal definition of the term "scalable lock" or "non-scalable lock". What it's meant to imply is that some locking algorithms, techniques or implementations perform reasonably well even when there is a lot of contention for the lock, and some do not.

Sometimes the problem is algorithmic. A naive implementation of priority inheritance, for example, may require O(n) work to release a lock, where n is the number of waiting threads. That implies O(n^2) work for every waiting thread to be serviced.

Sometimes the problem is to do with hardware. Simple spinlocks (e.g. implementations for which the lock cache line is shared and acquirers don't back off) don't scale on SMP hardware with a single bus interconnect, because writing to a cache line requires that the CPU acquires the cache line, and the CPU interconnect is a single point of contention. If there are n CPUs trying to acquire the same lock at the same time, you may end up with O(n) bus traffic to acquire the lock. Again, this means O(n^2) time for all n CPUs to be satisfied.

In general, you should avoid non-scalable locks unless two conditions are met:

1. Contention is light.
2. The critical section is very short.

You really have to *know* that the two conditions are met. A critical section may be short in terms of lines of code, but not be short in wall time. If in doubt, use a scalable lock, and later fix any which have been *measured* to cause performance problems.

As for your last question, I'm not aware of an off-the-shelf read-write lock which favours readers. Actually, most APIs don't specify policy, including pthreads (annoyingly).

My first comment is that you probably don't want it. If you have high contention, favouring one over the other kills throughput, and if you don't have high contention, it won't make a difference. About the only reason I can think not to use a rw lock with a completely fair policy is if you have thread priorities which must be respected, so you want the highest priority thread to be preferred.

But if you must, you could always roll your own. All you need is a couple of flags (one for "readers can go now" and one for "a writer can go now"), condition variables protecting the flags, a single mutex protecting the condition variables, and a couple of counters indicating how many readers and writers are waiting. That should be all you need; implementing this should be quite instructive.

Comment: super clear explanation. Thank you very much. I am totally agree with your comment regarding the throughput issue, but does not apply in my current suituation.