# Can someone give a simple example of using a non-scalable lock?

Tags: locking

I am bit confused about non-scalable locks .Can somebody give me an example and explain how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You use a non-scalable lock in the same way as a scalable-lock. The difference is, that with the non-scalable version you might get in trouble with high contention. On the other hand some non-scalable locks might be a bit more responsive if used lightly (which is very common scenario). See also: [What is a scalable lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059958/what-is-a-scalable-lock)

If you want a sample you need to specify programming language and lock primitive you want to (not) use.

Comment: Hi,I need a sample in Java using non-scalable lock.and thanks for the info.